make anchor tests run one after the other
So i'm writing tests for my anchor program, using the mocha testing framework (as per default)
Inside of my describe, I want to do different tests, so different it() instructions, but I need them to be ran one, then the other once the first is fully done, etc...
Because for example in the first one I initialise a token mint and mint some tokens, and in the second i need to have these tokens.
Pretty basic need but I can't figure out how to do this

This is more of a mocha-specific question, so normal Stack Overflow might be more useful, ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736429/how-can-i-execute-async-mocha-tests-nodejs-in-order
